# I don't understand the behavior of GPO

Tags: powershell, active-directory, system-administration, gpo

I recently received a powershell script that I have to deploy by GPO to all computers and servers. But before deploying it, I want to understand in deepth what will happen. I don't want to break a compagny Active Directory.

The script is a little sensitive, so let's take an example. In the script there is a line using the commandlet `New-ADUser @parameters` to create a new user in the Active Directory and another line for create a file on all computers.

My concern is about the execution of the script on computer. I think the commandlet `New-ADUser` is Domain Controller specific and it shouldn't work on a basic computer. But in the case it work, I don't want to create the same user dozens of times or something like that.

Will the script work without crashing by only selecting computer specific commandlet or should I expect different behaviour ?

I didn't try anything because I have to deploy the script to corporate clients. And as I mentioned I don't want to break anything.

Comment: "I think the commandlet New-ADUser is Domain Controller specific and it shouldn't work on a basic computer" - it's not, you can install the Active Directory module on any Windows computer (even non-domain-joined machines). If you want feedback on how a specific part of your script will behave, thenn please _show us the actual code_! :)

Comment: You're definitely going to have to provide us with code if you need help further with this. I would say, if your received the script from someone else though, you can also ask them about the specifics of the code. Good luck and welcome to StackOverflow!